# How to get number of video views with YouTube API V3?

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

i use this code to achieve this but this don't work :

```
 <?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=hqepb5hzuB0&key={YOUR-API-KEY}");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $json_data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
echo $views;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which line is failing? What error do you get?

Comment: I have nothing, no error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=hqepb5hzuB0&key={YOUR-API-KEY}");
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);
echo $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
```

Comment: What problem do you have with the code? Are you getting an error or incorrect data back?

Comment: Sorry. Used `Browser key` instead of the `Server key`.